# Word split in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a table

```sql
Create table emp_details(eno number,ename varchar2(22));
```

having values below

| eno | ename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | suresh kumar |
| 2 | ram kumar |

now i want to split the ename as two columns by using the space.

| eno | ename | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | suresh kumar | suresh | kumar |
| 2 | ram kumar | ram | kumar |

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions if the data set is not relatively huge

```sql
WITH emp_details(eno,ename) AS
(
 SELECT 1, 'suresh kumar'    FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'ram kumar'       FROM dual
)
SELECT eno, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ename,'[^ ]+') AS name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ename,'[^ ]+$') AS surname
  FROM emp_details
```

| ENO | NAME | SURNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | suresh | kumar |
| 2 | ram | kumar |

But if there can be people with names *more than one word* in the data set, then rather prefer using

```sql
WITH emp_details(eno,ename) AS
(
 SELECT 1, 'suresh kumar'    FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'ram kumar'       FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 'ram sahil kumar' FROM dual 
)
SELECT eno, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(ename, '^(.*) .*$', '\1') AS name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(ename,'[^ ]+$') AS surname
  FROM emp_details
```

| ENO | NAME | SURNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | suresh | kumar |
| 2 | ram | kumar |
| 3 | ram sahil | kumar |

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9008ceb08f5ba0d26338479ce2ab43db)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `INSTR` here for an option using base string options:

```sql
SELECT
    eno,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(ename, ' ') > 0
         THEN SUBSTR(ename, 1, INSTR(ename, ' ') - 1)
         ELSE ename END AS col1,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(ename, ' ') > 0
         THEN SUBSTR(ename, INSTR(ename, ' ') + 1) END AS col2
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The `CASE` expressions used above are there to ensure that a one word name gets assigned to the first name only.

Answer (score 0):

If names have two "words", then you might consider regular expressions.

```
SQL> select eno, regexp_substr(ename, '\w+', 1, 1) first_name,
  2              regexp_substr(ename, '\w+', 1, 2) last_name
  3  from emp_details;

       ENO FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 suresh     kumar
         2 ram        kumar

SQL>
```